# Creating a input method that prints right amount of days in a month/Int can't be converted into string

Tags: java

For my code I am supposed to set a method that will ask for the month for parameters then print out the right amount of days that month had.

I have developed if statements for each day of the month for when the user inputs a month, however, I keep getting a message saying `int cannot be converted into string`.

I was told I was suppose to return the number of days

[Example January should return 31]

however I am not exactly sure how to do this. Instead of trying to print "31" do I put in "return 31"?

```
import java.util.*;

public class findDays{
    public static String monthDays(int month){
        Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Type a month");
        month = key.nextInt();

        if (month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 8 || month == 10 || month == 12) 
        {
            System.out.println("31");
        }
        else if(month == 2)
        {
            System.out.println("28");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("30");
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Replace `public static String monthDays` with `public static void monthDays`

Comment: What if the year for Feb is a leap year?

Answer (score 1):

There would be no need to pass the argument, and using `java.time.*` library could help substantially.

Here is a suggestion as a replacement of the code above, specifying whether does the method return a number of days of a month in a leap year or not could enhance the functionality as well. 
The number of days in Month of February could be different if leap year:

```
public static String monthDays(boolean isLeapYear) {
    int month;
    Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Type a month (a number in range of 1 to 12)");
    month = key.nextInt();
    if (month > 12 || month < 1)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The month number is invalid.");
    int thisYear = LocalDate.now().getYear();
    YearMonth yearMonth;
    int year = 0;
    if (isLeapYear) {
        if (Year.of(thisYear).isLeap())
            year = thisYear;
        else {
            for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
                if (Year.of(thisYear + i).isLeap())
                    year = thisYear + i;
        }
    } else {
        if (Year.of(thisYear).isLeap())
            year = thisYear + 1;
        else
            year = thisYear;
    }
    yearMonth = YearMonth.of(year, month);
    System.out.println("Inserted month: " + yearMonth.getMonth());
    int monthDays = yearMonth.lengthOfMonth();
    System.out.println("Number of days in month: " + monthDays);
    return String.valueOf(monthDays);
}
```

This is noteworthy that both in your method and the suggested one, it is required to determine the year so that calculating the number of days in a month would be more accurate.

To start, we could set the year as currentYear and based on the leapYear flag and whether this year is a leap year or not, we will find out the number of days in the inserted month.

Hope that helps out.

Comment: damn, that's a good one, I didin't even remember the leap year on my answer, +1

Comment: well, the number of days in February could vary based on that.

Comment: Oh I'm not the one that asked it, I just wrote the other answer

Answer (score 0):

To return a value from a method, you'll use the `return` keyword followed by whichever value you want to return, in your case, you are just printing the value for each month, if you want to return it, change it to

```
if (month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 8 || month == 10 || month == 12) 
        {
            System.out.println("31");
            return "31";
        }
```

This will both print the value, and then return it.
Also you could implement a `switch case`, it is faster and cleaner than the if statement in cases like that:

```
switch(month) {
    case 1:
    case 3:
    case 5:
    //.... all your 31 day months here
    return 31;

    case 2:
    return 28;
    default: 
    return 30;
}
```

The default keyword means that, if the value does not match any of the case clauses, the default will be executed, similar to the `else` in your  code.

[This](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_switch.asp) article explains the switch statement in more detail if you wanna read more about it.